# Negative query issue in Lucene

Tags: lucene

Take a look at this query :

```
-HOSTNAME:ram AND SEVERITY:information
```

The above query isn't giving me the intended results. I know we need to append a * : * to a query that it is totally negative, also I found that the above case could be solved by appending a * : * to the HOSTNAME search criteria, but it might be a serious performance crunch, since my application gets search queries from the end user directly.

How do I go about this and help me arrive at an optimal solution please!

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work OK as written, However, including only negative terms does not work:

```
-HOSTNAME:ram AND -SEVERITY:ERROR
```

as there is nothing to subtract from (at least, that is the way I think of it).